# Quartz not delaying jobs already started in cluster environment

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have `Quartz` running in a cluster and I do get jobs running periodically. The job is started in one machine and the others will hold until next execution time.

What I want now is to delay the job invocation if the previous invocation isn't finished yet. For instance:

```
10:00 - instance invocation#1
10:06 - invocation#1 finished
10:10 - instance invocation#2
10:13 - invocation#2 finished
10:20 - instance invocation#3
10:31 - invocation#3 finished // took longer than expected
10:31 - instance invocation#4 // start delayed
10:35 - invocation#4 finished
```

Even this would be acceptable:

```
10:00 - instance invocation#1
10:06 - invocation#1 finished
10:10 - instance invocation#2
10:13 - invocation#2 finished
10:20 - instance invocation#3
10:31 - invocation#3 finished // took longer than expected
10:40 - instance invocation#4 // waits for next timed invocation
10:44 - invocation#4 finished
```

I'm using cron expression like triggers and it is triggered once each 10 minutes (`0 0/10 * * *`).

Answer (score 1):

Annotating your job with [`@DisallowConcurrentExecution`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html) should do the trick.

Comment: As far as I read this annotation only prevents a job to run on same node. My concern is more to delay the execution in a cluster environment.

Comment: binoternary is correct. @DisallowConcurrentExecution will do the trick. It will ensure at any given point in time only one instance of this job runs.